# Log django database queries using logging

Tags: django, logging

I want to log insert, update, delete and failed select query in my daily log file. I configured `django.db.backends` in the logger of the Logging dict in `settings.py`. But I get all the queries in that application. I need only insert, update, delete and failed select queries.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add this to you `settings.py`.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) may help you and [this article](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/) too.

Comment: It will log all the queries... I don't want all the select query in my  log, need insert, update, delete and failed select query.

Comment: Doesn't log anything.